# Why doesn't this append to sample.txt? cat demo.txt > cat sample.txt

Tags: bash, shell

Let say we have a text file demo.txt that only contains the word 'demo' and a text file sample.txt that only contains the word 'sample'.

I understand that `cat demo.txt > sample.txt` would append the contents of demo.txt into the contents of sample.txt.

But what happens when I have the cat command on both sides of the inequality? I've tried the same thing with single and double inequality. I've studied enough to know that you really want to use the double inequality if you don't want something overridden. I also know that the cat command is short for concatenation (it was a surprise to me that the 'cat' command can double as a txt print "function").

Comment: `>` is not an inequality; it's a redirection symbol. What's on its right-hand side is not a command; it's a filename to which the current command's output is redirected. (`cat` works as a `print` command precisely because its output is the terminal, unless redirected.) You really need to find a gentle introduction to the command line, I think.

Comment: A `|` can redirect the output of the first command to serve as input for the next

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  A heads-up that questions on Stack Overflow should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems" (i.e. programming).*  Non-programming WSL questions are usually better suited for one of the other Stack Exchange sites here such as [Super User](https://superuser.com), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), or (if the question is Ubuntu-specific) [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).  In this case, a general shell question is probably best for Unix & Linux.  You can use your Stack Overflow login there as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron thank you for correcting my verbiage... i'm still learning and appreciate the assist on proper terminology

Answer (score 1):

A redirection like `>` or `>>` always takes a *file name* on the right side. If you try to pass them a command name like `cat` they'll interpret it as a file name.

Redirections don't have to be at the end of a command. They can be anywhere: before, in the middle, or at the end. Also, spaces are optional after `>`, so for clarity in this answer I'm going to squeeze them out to show you how the shell interprets the command. These three commands are all equivalent:

```
cat demo.txt > cat sample.txt
cat demo.txt >cat sample.txt
cat demo.txt sample.txt >cat
```

All three of them write the contents of `demo.txt` and `sample.txt` to a file called `cat` in the current directory.

That's obviously not what you intend. If you want to append text to an existing file use `>>` instead of `>`:

```
cat demo.txt >> sample.txt
```

Comment: cool, but what about cat demo.txt >> cat sample.txt ?

Comment: @noriloxic Again: That would append to the file `cat` like John says in the answer. _"But what happens when I have the cat command on both sides of the inequality?"_ - You don't have a `cat` command on both sides of the redirection `>`. You have a filename named `cat` to the right side of it.

Answer (score -1):

`>` truncates the destination file first. `>>` appends to it, so try `cat demo.txt >> sample.txt`.

Comment: OK, but what about  [ cat demo.txt >> cat sample.txt ]    ?

Comment: @noriloxic That would append to the file `cat`...

Comment: Everything this answer states is correct, but it doesn't address the question OP is asking.